# Show answers when reviewing questions

Tags: feature-request, answers, review

Sometimes I find it very useful when looking at question in the review queue to see the answers. It helps give context to the question, especially if an answer is accepted.

Obviously I can just open the question in a new tab, but it would be nice to see the answers inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously I can just open the question in a new tab

I really can't think of a better UI than that. /review shows you one post at a time (+ the question, for answers) - when that's not enough, open a new tab with the full question and all the answers.

Genuine, Original /questions - accept no substitutes or imitations.

Comment: The nuisance value is that I then have to go to the tab, switch back, possibly repeat the process a couple of times, and eventually close the extra tab.  It would be nice — I agree with BNL — if the answers were available in a tab on the review page, like the possible duplicate question is available.  The information needed for the review is then all at hand.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with just clicking on the question title, skimming or reading the answers, comments, or whatever, and then going back?  For the Vote to Close queue, I do it all the time.  If a question seems borderline and has answers, I like to see what they are before deciding.